# MongoDB dot notation in Grails

Tags: grails, mongodb, grails-orm

I have some problem creating queries using [createCriteria()](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) in Grails 1.3.7 when using the [dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29) in MongoDB. I am using the [mongodb](http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb) plugin.

My domain class looks similar to this:

```
class Log {
    static mapWith = 'mongo'

    ObjectId id
    String name
    Map logicalIds = [:]
}
```

**Edit:** where *logicalIds* is a map of key/value of user dependent data, which is not known in beforehand.

And the query is created like this:

```
def c = Log.createCriteria()
c.list {
    eq('name', 'John Doe')
    eq('logicalIds.text', 'some text')
}
```

But the following exception is thrown:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property [logicalIds.text] is not a valid property of class [...]

Is this possible to fix, or is it not possible to use *createCriteria*?

**Answer:**
I could not make sense of the answer below so I came up with an alternative solution.
Instead of *createCriteria* I simply used the *find* function from [gmongo](https://github.com/poiati/gmongo) which accepts dot notation.